# How does laravel check if users are authenticated?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I might not understand the laravel authentication architecture, but it seems to me quite hard to understand how does the `Auth::check()` function actually work, since it doesn't get any parameter as an input. Precisely, my question, is how does the function know what user is checking?

Comment: This method is not meant to check if a specific username is logged, it's meant to check if the user attempting a connection is logged (or not). So the method will return true even if the user who load the page is logged with somebody else's credentials.

Comment: look this page.`http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/authentication-with-laravel-4/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `Auth::check()` has following code

```
public function check()
{
    return ! is_null($this->user());
}
```

The function `Auth::user()` returns the user instance if any user is logged in or null if none is logged in. So, it's not checking who is logged in but it only checks if any user is logged in or not.

Whenever a user logs in to the application, the `Auth::login()` function does this at first

```
$this->updateSession($id = $user->getAuthIdentifier());
```

This code is self-explanatory, it just updates the `session`, here `$user->getAuthIdentifier()` returns the primary key of the logged in user and `Auth::updateSession()` function simply runs this

```
$this->session->put($this->getName(), $id);
```

Here, `$this->getName()` returns an `md5` string which is being used as the `key` and `$id` is the logged in user id, so it just puts the user id in the session associated with a key (unique `md5` string).

So, actually the `Auth::check()` triggers the `Auth::user()` function and that function mainly checks the session for this `md5` key and if this `key` is available in the session then it contains an integer value which is the user id.

The key looks something like this `login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc` and it may contain an integer value of user id if any user is logged in.

This is a sample of session data when a user is logged in

```
array (size=4)
    '_token' => string 'CmHN90G2sVWvejx9r6MMo8AU2dhhV8z9BJQPzATt' (length=40)
    'flash' => 
        array (size=2)
            'old' => array (size=0) empty
            'new' => array (size=0)   empty
        'login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc' => int 1 <-- current user id
        '_sf2_meta' => 
            array (size=3)
                'u' => int 1391189690
                'c' => int 1391187210
                'l' => string '0' (length=1)
```